# Error: Attempt to read property "num_rows" on boo

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo validaciones para no repetir datos, en este caso el dato es el usuario pero me esta tirando error en la linea 223 en class Usuario..

```
public static function ValidarUsuario($usuario){
    $sql ="SELECT (usuario.usuario) as user FROM usuario WHERE 'user'=". $usuario ; 
    echo $sql;
    $database = new MySQL();

    $datos = $database->consultar($sql);

    if ($datos->num_rows > 1){ //EL ERROR
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

Yo pienso que el error es que el nombre "usuario" se llama lo mismo que la tabla y que el sistema no sabe como interpretarlo y por eso le cambie de nombre con el AS pero el error sigue ahi, pero la verdad que estoy en dudas

Les paso tambien la otra parte del codigo donde utilizo esta funcion.

```
<?php
    require_once "../../class/Usuario.php";

    $usuario = $_GET["usuario"];
    $resultado="";

    if (Usuario::ValidarUsuario($usuario)==true){
        $resultado="true";
    }else{
        $resultado="false";
    }
    echo $resultado;
?>
```

Tambien la parte del ajax y validacion.

```
function validarUsuario2(){
    var usuario = document.getElementById('varusuario')
    validarCampo(expresiones.usuario,varusuario, 'usuario');
}
function validarUsuario(){
    var usuario = $('#varusuario').val();
    var campo = "usuario";
    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url:"ComprobarUsuario.php",
        data:{usuario: usuario}
    })

    .done(function(respuesta){
        alert(respuesta)
        
        if(respuesta == "false" ){
            document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.add('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
            document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.remove('formulario__grupo-correcto');
            document.querySelector(`#grupo__${campo} .formulario__input-error2`).classList.add('formulario__input-error2-activo');

            campos[campo] = false;

        }else if(respuesta =="true"){
            document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.remove('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
            document.getElementById(`grupo__${campo}`).classList.add('formulario__grupo-correcto');
            document.querySelector(`#grupo__${campo} .formulario__input-error2`).classList.remove('formulario__input-error2-activo');
            campos[campo] = true;
        }

    })
}
```

Cabe aclarar que esto ya lo hice con DNI, pero solamente en USUARIOS tengo el error.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Estás poniendo comillas en la columna en lugar del valor, en todo caso, la columna va entre acentos graves: `\`user\` = '$usuario';"` Por otra parte, te recomiendo ejecutar esa consulta en PhpMyAdmin para que veas si hay errores.

Comment: Si lo prob[e y me tira error #1054 - La columna 'user' en where clause es desconocida

Comment: Precisamente, la consulta no se ejecuta correctamente y por eso obtienes `bool` (false) al ejecutarla. ¿Por qué usas alias si solo estás obteniendo una columna de una sola tabla? Intenta con: `SELECT usuario FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario'` y no olvides probar primero en PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Lo habia probado asi anteriormente y me daba error, ahora nuevamente lo volvi aprobar y anduvo, seguro no habre actualizado o no se habra actualizado bien la chache. Muchas gracias!